# Read list of files with inconsistent delimiter/fixed width

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to find a more efficient way to import a list of data files with a kind of awkward structure. The files are generated by a software program that looks like it was intended to be printed and viewed rather than exported and used. The file contains a list of "Compounds" and then some associated data. Following a line reading "Compound X: XXXX", there are a lines of tab delimited data. Within each file the number of rows for each compound remains constant, but the number of rows may change with different files.

Here is some example data:

```
#Generate two data files to be imported
 cat("Quantify Compound Summary Report\n", 
    "\nPrinted Mon March 28 14:54:39 2022\n", 
    "\nCompound 1: One\n", 
    "\tName\tID\tResult", 
    "\n1\tA1234\tQC\t25.2", 
    "\n2\tA4567\tQC\t26.8\n", 
    "\nCompound 2: Two\n", 
    "\tName\tID\tResult", 
    "\n1\tA1234\tQC\t51.1", 
    "\n2\tA4567\tQC\t48.6\n",
    file = "test1.txt")
 cat("Quantify Compound Summary Report\n", 
    "\nPrinted Mon March 28 14:54:39 2022\n", 
    "\nCompound 1: One\n", 
    "\tName\tID\tResult", 
    "\n1\tC1234\tQC\t25.2", 
    "\n2\tC4567\tQC\t26.8", 
    "\n3\tC8910\tQC\t25.4\n", 
    "\nCompound 2: Two\n", 
    "\tName\tID\tResult", 
    "\n1\tC1234\tQC\t51.1", 
    "\n2\tC4567\tQC\t48.6",
    "\n3\tC8910\tQC\t45.6\n",
    file = "test2.txt")
```

What I want in the end is a list of data frames, one for each "Compound", containing all rows of data associated with each compound. To get there, I have a fairly convoluted approach of smashed together functions which give me what I want but in a very unruly fashion.

```
library(tidyverse)

## Step 1: ID list of data files
data.files <- list.files(path = ".",
                         pattern = ".txt",
                         full.names = TRUE)
## Step 2: Read in the data files
data.list.raw <- lapply(data.files, read_lines, skip = 4) 

## Step 3: Identify the "compounds" in the data file output  
Hdr.dat <- lapply(data.list.raw, function(x) grepl("Compound", x)) # Scan the file and find the different compounds within it (this can be applied to any Waters output)
grp.dat <- Map(function(x, y) {x[y][cumsum(y)]}, data.list.raw, Hdr.dat)

## Step 4: Unpack the tab delimited parts of the export file, then generate a list of dataframes within a list of imported files
Read <- function(x) read.table(text = x, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
raw.dat <- Map(function(x,y) {Map(Read, split(x, y))}, data.list.raw, grp.dat)

## Step 5: Curate the list of compounds - remove "Compound X: " 
cmpd.list <- lapply(raw.dat, function(x) trimws(substring(names(x), 13))) 

## Step 6: Rename the headers for the dataframes, remove the blank rows and recentre 
NameCols <- function(z) lapply(names(z), function(i){
  x <- z[[ i ]]
  colnames(x) <- x[2,]
  x[c(-1,-2),]
})
data.list <- Map(function(x,y){setNames(NameCols(x), y)}, raw.dat, cmpd.list) 

## Step 7: rbind the data based on the compound 
cmpd_names <- unique(unlist(sapply(data.list, names)))

result <- list()
j <- for (n in cmpd_names) {
  result[[n]] <- map(data.list, n)
}
list.merged <- map(result, dplyr::bind_rows)

list.merged <- lapply(list.merged, function(x) x %>% filter(Name != ""))
```

The challenge here is script efficiency as far as time (I can import hundreds or thousands of data files with hundreds of lines of data, which can take quite a while) as well as general "cleanliness", which is why I included `tidyverse` as a tag here. I also want this to be highly generalizable, as the "Compounds" may change over time. If someone can come up with a clean and efficient way to do all of this I would be forever in your debt.

Comment: The example offered appears to have multiple duplicates or collisions. Your answer also strips the leading characters from the name so they are then "ne" and "wo". But it doesn't seem to address the duplication issue.

Comment: See updated script. I decreased the substring value to 13 to fix the "ne" and "wo" (this is just a difference between my example data and real data files). In the end, this is integrated into a `shiny` script, so it's cleaner to have the compound name rather than saying "Compound 1: XXX" every time. *Note I also added the lone library `tidyverse` that I used to make this script work without errors or collisions.

Comment: As far as I can tell you are completely ignoring the question of collisions of date/time, compound and ID/value.  These appear to be exact duplicates and not worthy of including in a master list.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your comment about collisions. There are no dates or times in the pertinent rows of data (the first few rows which contain the date the file was created are removed in the final product - see example output). So that makes we curious what collisions you are referring to?

Comment: The contents of `data.list.raw[[1]]` seem to be the same as the contents of `data.list.raw[[2]]` except for additional values.  The context of the problem wasn't described so I thought this might be a "database" updating problem. I'm not sure where I got the "date/time" column designation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See one approach below. The whole pipeline might be intimidating at first glance. You can insert a `head` (or `tail`) call after each step (`%>%`) to display the current stage of data transformation. There's a bit of cleanup with *regular expressions* going on in the `gsub`s: modify as desired.

```
intermediate_result <-
data.frame(file_name = c('test1.txt','test2.txt')) %>%
    rowwise %>%
    ## read file content into a raw string:
    mutate(raw = read_file(file_name)) %>%
    ## separate raw file contents into rows 
    ## using newline and carriage return as row delimiters:
    separate_rows(raw, sep = '[\\n\\r]') %>%
    ## provide a compound column for later grouping
    ## by extracting the 'Compound' string from column raw
    ## or setting the compound column to NA otherwise:
    mutate(compound = ifelse(grepl('^Compound',raw),
                             gsub('.*(Compound .*):.*','\\1', raw),
                             NA)
           ) %>%
    ## remove rows with empty raw text:
    filter(raw != '') %>%
    ## filling missing compound values (NAs) with last non-NA compound string:
    fill(compound, .direction = 'down') %>%
    ## keep only rows with tab-separated raw string
    ## indicating tabular data
    filter(grepl('\\t',raw)) %>%
    ## insert a column header 'Index' because
    ## original format has four data columns but only three header cols:
    mutate(raw = gsub(' *\\tName','Index\tName',raw))
```

Above steps result in a dataframe with a column 'raw' containing the cleaned-up data as string suited for conversion into tabular data (tab-delimited, linefeeds).
From there on, we can either proceed by keeping and householding the future single tables inside the parent table as a so-called [list column](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/how-to-work-with-list-columns/) (Variant A) or proceed with splitting column 'raw' and mapping it (Variant B, *credits to* @Dorton).

*Variant A* produces a column of dataframes inside the dataframe:

```
intermediate_result %>%
   group_by(compound) %>%
    ## the nifty piece: you can store dataframes inside a dataframe:
    mutate(
        tables = list(read.table(text = raw, header = TRUE, sep = '\t' ))
    )
```

*Variant B* produces a list of dataframes named with the corresponding compound:

```
intermediate_result %>%
    split(f = as.factor(.$compound)) %>% 
    lapply(function(x) x %>%
                       separate(raw,
                                into = unlist(
                                    str_split(x$raw[1], pattern = "\t"))
                                )
           )
```

Comment: This solution gets me about 99% of the way to where I want to be. If I skip the dataframes within dataframes step (interesting, just not how I need to have the data organized for filtering in my final app) and add `split(f = as.factor(.$compound)) %>%
        lapply(function(x) x %>% separate(raw, into = unlist(str_split(t$raw[1], pattern = "\t"))))` after the `mutate` step, I get exactly what I was after! If you can add these lines I can accept the answer.

Comment: @Dorton: thank you - also for the inspiring initial question! I wouldn't be surprised were there already a dedicated function inside one of the zillion packages - perhaps some `sed` emulation, but finding it would've taken me longer than the script itself.